# Поиск по landing-page с помощью скрола к тексту введенному в input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как быстро и легко реализовать просто поиск по сайту (лендинг - page), чтобы в input можно было вводить какой то текст и после нажатия на enter например, происходил скрол к введенному тексту если он есть на странице конечно же, заранее всех благодарю за помощь

Comment: можно сделать к блоку, в котором находится текст, если вам нужна еще и строка, то тут будет не тривиально

Answer (score 1):

Находит последний элемент, который содержит данную фразу на странице, и прокручивает ее.

```
const search = $('.search-input').val();
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains("+search+":last").offset().top);
```

Comment: к сожалению ваш код не работает

Comment: @Houckz покажите пример вашего html.